# Percentage difference between two images

Tags: image, image-processing, automation, pixel

I have two images of same height/width they look like similar.But they are not exactly similar pixel by pixel.That is one of the image is moved to right by few pixels.

I am currently using imagemagick compare command.It shows difference as it compares pixel by pixel.Also i tried with fuzz attribute of it.

Please suggest any other tool to compare such type of images.

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to perform? Should horizontal shifts be detected as a difference? How would you want the percentage be calculated? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: in above case it should show me perfect match.That is 0% difference

Comment: So you are looking for a continguous rectangle from image A in image B, and if this common subimage can be identified, it is a 100% match? Makes sense if you set a minimum size for the common subimage.

Comment: My previous comment suggests part of an algorithm to do the comparison...find an as-large-as-possible common subimage of both images, and calculate a match percentage depending upon the size of the subimage in relation to the original size. I think you´ll have to code that from fresh, although image recognition libraries might have this functionality.

Comment: But what about images that are identical except for say 1% of all pixels? Or images that are 100% different, but the pixels differ by very small values only? Match? Mismatch? X% match? What if two images have both properties -- high pixel similarity (but not equal pixel values) AND spatial shift? What about distorted images -- partial match? You should analyze those requirements beforehand (i.e. before considering algorithms, tools, and implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're really trying to achieve, but if you want a metric to express the similitude between the two images without taking image displacement into account, then maybe you should work in the frequency domain.

As instance, the frequency part of the DFT of your images should be nearly identical, so if you compute the SNR of the two frequency parts, it should be practically null.

In fact, according to the Fourier shift theorem, you can even get an estimation of the displacement offset by calculating the inverse DFT of the combination of the two DFT.